# Access NSTimer from one class to another class

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6

I have class one.m and in class one.m defined NSTimer

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.6
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateView:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

How i can access this NSTimer in mainviewcontroller to pause and resume it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the timer a property, and then access it from the `MainViewController` class.
Just like this

```
@interface One: UIDelegate {
    //variables
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSTimer* myTimer;

@implementation One
@synthesize myTimer;
//other

@implementation MainViewController
One *one = [[One alloc]init];
one.myTimer; //now you can access the timer
```

Comment: That is what i m doing but it is saying unknown receiver myTimer did you mean NSTimer. No known class method for selector invalidate

Comment: You don't want to call NSTimer, because then you haven't specified which timer you want to stop. Try to run this through the debugger, and see if your `myTimer` in class `One` is the same as the `one.myTimer` in the `MainViewController`